# Composition of a trigonometric function and its reciprocal

Tags: trigonometry

I've managed to severely confuse myself in my attempts to simplify this seemingly straightforward expression:
$$
\arctan(\cot(\alpha)),\quad\text{with $0<\alpha\leq\pi$.}
$$
It seems like maybe there are some issues with domain, as $\cot$ and $\tan$ are defined on $(0,\pi)$ and $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, respectively.  However, $\arctan$ *is* able to "deal" with the fact that $\cot(\pi)=-\infty$, since its limit exists at negative infinity.

What method should I be using to simplify this?  I believe that I should be getting $\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$, but I'm not sure how to show it symbolically.

Answer (score 2):

One way to see this is to calculate the derivative of $\arctan(\cot(\alpha))$, which is identically equal to $-1$. Therefore, since you are restricting yourself to the interval $(0, \pi)$, you can conclude that your expression is equal, on that interval, to $-\alpha + c$ for some $c \in \mathbb R$. Finally, setting $\alpha = \pi/2$ gives $c = \pi/2$.

p.s. Even if the limit of $\arctan(\cot(\alpha))$ as $\alpha \to \pi$ is finite, you still can't evaluate that expression at $\alpha = \pi$. Same thing happens at zero, by the way!

Comment: Very interesting approach.  And good point about the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a right triangle with one of the angles being $\alpha$. Label the leg that contains angle $\alpha$ to be $x$ and the opposite leg to be of length 1. This way, $$\cot(\alpha)=x$$ Now let's investigate $\arctan(x)$. Since the third angle of this right triangle measures $\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$, you know that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)=x$, and it follows that $\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$.

Note: Due to the domain restrictions, this formula does *not* hold at $\alpha=\frac{k\pi}{2}$, where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: This is how I originally attempted to solve this, but then I got into trouble when $\frac{\pi}{2}<\alpha\leq\pi$.  How does it work in that case?

Comment: Just draw the same triangle in a coordinate plane, except this time one vertex is in the second quadrant. You should obtain the same results in all four quadrants.